# Set fields in uc_addresses checkout pane to disabled

Tags: forms, ubercart, panels

I want to disable the billing address fields in `uc_addresses` so they cannot be altered by the user while they're checking out.  However, I cannot find a form to use `hook_form_alter` on.  It seems those fields are living inside a pane, but I don't know how to isolate and edit that.

I suppose this is one of those times they told me about where all I want to do is hack the other modules.

**edit1**:
If you're interested [here's the function](http://pastebin.com/0Ta6Bnaq) that controls the panes and calls up the form.  I don't really understand how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I finally figured it out:

```
function YOUR_MODULE_form_uc_cart_checkout_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  $form['panes']['delivery']['#disabled'] = TRUE;

}
```

They're all greyed out and uneditable -- a work of art really.

Answer (score 0):

It must be a form and You can alter via [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7).
But in function you should must check the form_id and after that print_r or dpr or dsm (whatever you like ) the $form. And search for the address field and unset it.

Comment: I agree.  How do I find out what form to hook into?

Comment: Look, There must be a form_id in there. 
Find that id by print_r($form_id) and go on.
No need of hooks i guess

Comment: yeah thats what I used I was just alittle out of practice and hook_form_alter had some confusing rules I needed to understand.

Comment: yup better clear your concepts
:)